# Why does my background image disappear sometimes?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, styles

I'm really stressed about this, it's all of a sudden started to happen. It's a WordPress site, so excuse the logo of the site not working and so on... this is just one page saved as HTML.

Link: http://bit.ly/1n7maKZ

For some reason, if I leave a page open for a certain amount of time, or click on a link and then go back to it, the backup background color will kick in suddenly and the background image will disappear! I have no idea why. I'm using Chrome.

My code in the header looks like this:

```
<div id="background" class="background-size grayscale bg"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#background {
    background: url("[WORKING LINK HERE]") no-repeat center center fixed #e1e1e1;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And...

```
.bg , #supersized {
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-20;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this? The annoying thing is, you probably won't get to see the issue because I have no idea what triggers it to suddenly drop the background image and resort to the alternate color. If I have a page open long enough in Chrome at least, it does it. Thank you for any help!

Comment: The file size is 910kb....that's a lot. You should try and reduce that.

Comment: My guess would be the filesize. >900 kB is way too large for a 'simple' background image. Get a good JPEG, make it a bit fussy, and you'll have the same effect.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Load'` (Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. )... Check out the developer tools, and address the warnings first.

Answer (score 0):

Your "WORKING LINK HERE" is not working at all. I tried to load the background.png file, but it doesn't exist and, after a while, the server gives you back the website's homepage.

Probably you sometime see the background because it is cached in your browser.

Fix the path/filename of you background image in your css and it will work.